# How to generate a CSV file from Overpass with ID and tag value?

Tags: overpass-api

I am trying to use http://overpass-turbo.eu ... Something as

```
[out:csv(::id, wikidata)];
way["wikidata"];
out center;
```

PS: the answer can restrict area to a country by a kind of `area["ISO3166-1"="BR"][boundary=administrative]` filter... Or more specific administrative area.

A table with the pair of `osm_id` and [`wikidata_id`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:wikidata)  of each tagged way of the map... And I need also to *limit* (use a SQL-like LIMIT clause) to test some other variants before request full query.

---

### NOTE 1 - Other solutions

Perhaps [taginfo.openstreetmap.org](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/search?q=wikidata#keys) also can generate this CSV, but I not see how to.

### NOTE 2 - Overpass answer at comments

I am testing regegular expression but was ignored

```
[out:csv(::id, wikidata)][timeout:25];
(
  way["wikidata"~"Q[0-9]+"]({{bbox}});
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

The answer was  posted by @mmd as comment http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/A84

```
[out:csv(::id, wikidata)][timeout:25];
way["wikidata"~"Q[0-9]+"]({{bbox}});
out 10;
```

where `out 10` is the answer for the "LIMIT clause" problem for tests or sampling...

### NOTE 3 - Other solution for non-limited CSV

Overpass will not run without a "limit parameter", so @mmd suggested other solution, that is not Overpass... I agree.

PS:  the answer can also use terminal and some tool as the suggested by @mmd,  as [osmium-tags-filter](https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool/blob/master/man/osmium-tags-filter.md) is perhaps a better solution.

Comment: 266 976 rows is really too much for an online query. Either restrict it by a bounding box, or better use a Planet dump to extract the data. Your second query needs different out statements, but basically works: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/A83

Comment: Hi @mmd it seems that the "limit clause" is `timeout`, so I edit and using it at an example, that will generate a good sample... But now the problem is to filter.

Comment: You can restrict the number by using out 10; as an example. timeout is _no_ limit clause, it will return either all or nothing.

Comment: @mmd, can you answer with a complete (and simplest!) syntax? I need only a sample set, but need that regular expression filter work fine... Need two columns non-empty.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you, http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/A84 - just replace out center; by out 10; to get 10 entries only.

Comment: @mmd yes, it is the answer!   There are some tool to do the same thing at terminal and downloading the full CSV?

Comment: Again, there's no meaningful way to download 266976 entries for the whole planet this way. Please use some other approach.

Comment: @mmd thanks, I can reduce by administrative area or country, see my edit with PS.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do in the first place? If you want to run this whole thing for the planet, even split into multiple queries, better look at downloading a full planet PBF file and process it via osmium-tool: https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool/blob/master/man/osmium-tags-filter.md

Comment: @mmd, hum... make sense, it will be the best answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, your example with "ISO3166-1"="BR" above doesn't work. It will only filter based on the bounding box, the area has no effect. Please check out the docs how (area) is supposed to be used: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_area_.28area.29

Comment: Hi @mmd, I edited all the question. It is a question, not a solution, so `"ISO3166-1"="BR"`  is only to show an intention, not a part of real script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of discussion and **no answer**  because Overpass is only for a first prospection... The "full data into a CSV" solution need a specialized tool and/or to extract directelly from "planet" XML file.  So, this answer is kind of  "Other solutions".

### Transforming the  map's XML-dump into desired CSV

At the time when I posted the question, I posted also a Github's draft solution, as [`simple-osmWd2csv` v0.0.1](https://github.com/OSMBrasil/simple-osmWd2csv/releases/tag/v0.0.1). Summary:

1. Get the full XML dump of region, that in general is a big `.osm.pbf` file, so you need also to extract with `osmium cat -f osm file.osm.pbf -o file.osm`
2. Pre-parse: [simplify the big XML](https://github.com/OSMBrasil/simple-osmWd2csv/blob/v0.0.1/src/osmWd2csv_pre.sh) to reduce the CPU time in the next step.
3. [Parse the residual XML](https://github.com/OSMBrasil/simple-osmWd2csv/blob/v0.0.1/src/osmWd2csv.php) generationg a CSV as result.

Ideal will be to develop an [`osmium`](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) module, parsing directally the [PBF](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) file... For more details and other solutions see (and help to enhance!)  https://github.com/OSMBrasil/simple-osmWd2csv